# Android : SensorListener

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am building a small application where I need to detect the motion of the device only when its in my hands not when it's in the pocket .

Right now, I built the application but the sensor event gets triggered when I am walking or running and the mobile its in my pocket?

Is there anyway to invoke the sensor changed ONLY when someone holds a device?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: "Is there anyway to invoke the sensor changed ONLY when someone holds a device?" The API doesn't have a method like this and I'm not sure how it would reliably make the distinction. You could only track movement when the screen is on...

Comment: try to work with a proximity-sensor or light-sensor to detect if it is in a pocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) intent to first check if the phone is being used or is in standby. After that you can implement the [Accelerometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) to detect motion. Here's an example:

```
public class SensorsActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
      private SensorManager sensorManager;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensors);

          sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

          sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                  sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){

      }

         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
              // check sensor type
          if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                        // TODO after accelerometer detected do something here
          }
      }
}
```

For your [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) detection you will need a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) with:

```
public class SensorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                  // TODO notify the user is present
            }
      }
}
```

And declare it in your *Manifest.xml* like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SensorReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope it helps!